# C++ fwrite access violation when writing image file

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to append RGB frame to file on each call.

Here is what I do :

```
        size_t lenght=_viewWidth * _viewHeight * 3;
    BYTE *bytes=(BYTE*)malloc(lenght);
    ///////////////  read pixels from  OpenGL tex  /////////////////////
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bytes);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);

        ///write it to file :
         hOutFile = fopen( outFileName.c_str(), cfg.appendMode ? "ab" : "wb" );
    assert(hOutFile!=0);


    fwrite(bytes, 1 ,w * h, hOutFile); // Write 



    fclose(hOutFile);
```

Somehow I am getting access violation when fwrite gets called.Probably I misunderstood how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you determine `_viewWidth` and `_viewHeight`? When reading back a texture you should retrieve them with [*glGetTexLevelparameteri*](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexLevelParameter.xml) to retrieve the *GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH*, and *GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT* parameters from the *GL_TEXTURE_2D* target.

Also the line

```
fwrite(bytes, 1 ,w * h, hOutFile);
```

is wrong. What is `w`, what is `h`? They never get initialized in the code and are not connected to the other allocations up there. Also if those are width and height of the image, it still lacks the number of elements of a pixel. Most likely 3.

It would make more sense to have something like

```
int elements = ...; // probably 3
int w = ...;
int h = ...;
size_t bytes_length = w*elements * h;
bytes = malloc(bytes_length)

... 

fwrite(bytes, w*elements, h, hOutFile);
```

Comment: w and h are initialized to the width and height of the image.But now I think fwrite params I pass are wrong.Why do you pass "h" only as the third parameter?

Comment: @MichaelIV: fwrite is part of C standard library IO, which is usually buffered. The 1st parameter to fwrite is the pointer to the buffer. 2nd parameter is the size of a single element in the buffer (in our case say a single row of pixels). The 3rd parameter is the number of elements of size specified before in the buffer. The 4th parameter is the pointer to a stdio FILE object. Passing the length of a row as element size gives a hint to stdio, what a good buffering size is.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Is it caused by `bytes`?
maybe `w * h` is not what you think it is.

Comment: w * h is width and height of the image

Comment: @MichaelIV: You think that, but are they properly defined and initialized in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Is the width ever an odd number or not evenly divisible by 4?

By default OpenGL assumes that a row of pixel data is aligned to a four byte boundary. With RGB/BGR this isn't always the case, and if so you'll be writing beyond the malloc'ed block and clobbering something. Try putting

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
```

before reading the pixels and see if the problem goes away.